# Getting pip pystruct==0.3.2 to build under python=3.7

Tags: pip, cython, python-3.7

There is no current solution for building pystruct 0.3.2 under python=3.7 because of an issue with support for python<=3.6 and resulting in a build time error related to curexc_traceback not being found. Also the utils.pyx file is not circulated with the pip tarball, resulting in an inability to rebuild the cython package that appears in the github version, as opposed to the pypi version. How can we patch and build pystruct==0.3.2 from pip?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if you combine the github version and pypi version, you can find a way that allows you to build the pip version as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VERSION=0.3.2

pip download pystruct==${VERSION}
git clone https://github.com/pystruct/pystruct
tar xzf pystruct-${VERSION}.tar.gz
mv pystruct-${VERSION}/src/utils.c pystruct-${VERSION}/src/utils.save
cp pystruct/src/utils.pyx pystruct-${VERSION}/src/
cython pystruct-${VERSION}/src/utils.pyx
cd pystruct-${VERSION} && python ./setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the only method I found to get it installed properly on Py3.7.9